# Ubuntu installation unable to detect ssd

Tags: hp-pavilion

I just bought a hp pavilion notebook. It has 1 TB ssd and windows10 installed in gpt scheme. I made 500 GB unallocated space and tried installing ubuntu on that. I disabled secure boot. But neither ubuntu installation nor "try ubuntu" gparted is able to detect the ssd. I tried different things suggested by the users bit nothing is working. Tried usb media gpt and mbr alternatively. My bios has limited option. Can not switch between AHCI to RAID. Also Intel rst is always active. No option to turn it off.

Comment: with Intel RST permanently on and no way to turn it off, you're going to have a lot of trouble.  Intel RST and the Ubuntu installer do not work together.  Unless you can disable Intel RST and go from RAID to AHCI, there's no way to make this work.  Are you sure that you didn't see these options in BIOS?  Because I have seen them in Pavillion BIOS - they're not in an obvious location though.  (Haven't got a Pavillion in front of me to figure where they are but there ARE options in HPs for that)

Comment: Yeah. I didn't see any such option. It shows the Intel RST but when I move there it's only showing the details of the ssd. No option to turn it off.

Comment: I can send you the pictures if you are available.

Comment: This user installed an Intel Optane app. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2458373 & https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/intel-optane-memory-and-storage-management/9mzng5hzwz1t?activetab=pivot:overviewtab

Comment: No.... for my system there is no optane memory and app is also not there...